# Get script element in DOM tree

Tags: javascript, dom

I have JavaScript code inside a `<script>` tag in the HTML body. How can I find the reference  of this `<script>` element from inside?

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
...
<div id="mydiv">
<script>
    var thisElement = getScriptElement(); //I'm asking if this kind of function exists
    thisElement.parentNode == document.getElementById("mydiv"); //these two should be equal

</script>
</div>
...
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: why do you want to do this? What's your ultimate goal?

Comment: @Sid I load JSON data into a  JS variable and I want to generate a table right there from JS

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you're trying to accomplish but here you go

```
<div id="mydiv">

  <script id="myScript">
    var thisScript = document.getElementById('myScript');
    var isInsideMe = thisScript.parentNode == document.getElementById("mydiv");
    alert( isInsideMe ); // true
  </script> 

</div>
```

or you can use (without setting an ID) `var thisScript = document.scripts[0];` if you're sure all your other scripts are placed before `</body>`

Comment: Thanks, these are working alternatives but I was looking for `document.currentScript`

Comment: @balping I was about to add that one. You were faster. I'll keep my answer as an alternative reference in the case `currentScript` will not reference the `<script>` element if the code if the script is being called as a callback or event handler; it will only reference the element while it's initially being processed.

Comment: Yes, but I can still save it to a variable and use it later. Here's my example: http://jsfiddle.net/8gueF/

Answer (score 0):

This is what I was looking for: `document.currentScript`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.currentScript

A working example: http://jsfiddle.net/8gueF/

Comment: Just a suggestion, you should consider editing your question so it's more clear what the problem is, and then edit this answer to make it more clear how this solves that problem. That will help others who have the same problem and will be your legacy. Hope this helps.

Comment: You might want to test support for that, quite a high percentage of browsers in use do not support *currentScript*. There are more robust ways of finding the "current script element" while the document is loading, but it's pretty difficult (and usually not required) after that.